# Iterate from TD element and get value

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value of my TD for deleting date of my database,

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('table#delTable td a.delete').click(function()
            {
                if (confirm("Eliminare il record?"))
                {
                    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                    var numero = $("#unico").text();
                    id = numero;
                    var data = 'id=' + id;
                    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

                    $.ajax(
                    {
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "Database",
                           data: data,
                           cache: false,

                           success: function()
                           {
                            parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                           }
                     });
                }
            });

            $('table#delTable tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
final String selezione = ("SELECT * FROM anagrafica");
ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    Statement st = (Statement) cm.getConnection().createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(selezione);
    out.print("<table align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' width='30%' id='delTable' bgcolor='#f6f6f6' style='border:1px solid #cccccc;'>");
    out.print("<table align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' width='30%' id='delTable' bgcolor='#f6f6f6' style='border:1px solid #cccccc;'>");
    out.print("<tbody><tr>");
    out.print("<th align='left' style='border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'><strong>Nome</strong></th>");
    out.print("<th align='center' style='border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'><strong>Cognome</strong></th>");
    out.print("</tr>");
    while (rs.next()) {
        out.print("<tr width id='1' style='background: rgb(255, 255, 255);'>");
        out.print("<td align='left'>"+rs.getString("Nome")+ "</td>");
        out.print("<td align='center'>"+rs.getString("Cognome")+ "</td>");
        out.print("<td style = 'display:none' id = 'unico' align='right'>"+rs.getInt("Id_unico")+ "</td>");
        out.print("<td align='center'><a href='#' class='delete' style='color:#FF0000;'><img alt='' align='absmiddle' border='0' src='delete.png'>"+"</a></td>");
}
    out.print("</tr>");
    out.print("</tbody></table>");
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    sqle.printStackTrace();
} finally{
     try {
         if(cm.getConnection()!=null) cm.getConnection().close();
         rs.close();
     } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
%>
```

But if I have 3 `td` rows which contains: 1, 2 and 3 if i click the first row the database deletes the record with id unique (1) and that's ok,

but if i click the second row always id 1 is deleted, because even if my TD has 30 rows the value is always about the first one,

I should iterate inside the td, how can i iterate the HTML elements.

Comment: Side note: Use `$(this).closest('tr')` rather then depend on the DOM structure with `$(this).parent().parent()`.

Comment: Also you will get better results here if you post the output HTML, rather than the source. Use your browser to save-as the page.

Comment: Before you can get the js to work you have to clean up the html: `<table>` is double, all `<tr>` has same id (=1), `<tr width>` has no value, ...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
var numero = $("#unico").text();
id = numero;
```

First init an `id` variable, and then do nothing with it. After create a `numero` variable, and overwrite your `id` with that `numero` value. I am assuming your `$("#unico").text();` is 1.

What you do is equal with this:

```
var id = $("#unico").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Right thank you, I forgotten to remove it since I was doing few tries, i changed it as: `var id = $("#unico").text();`but the problem still occurs.